# Detecting force of pressure on Custom ImageView in UIKit

Tags: swift, uikit, uiimageview, 3dtouch

I have developed a custom ImageView in my iOS app that can be moved around by the user.

Now I want to determine the precise pressure applied to the ImageView using 3D Touch while it is being moved. Currently, my implementation only provides binary information (pressure applied or not). Is it feasible to continuously monitor and measure the force exerted on the ImageView with more precision during movement?

If so, how can I accomplish this using UIKit?

Comment: Be aware that devices after the iPhone XS do not have 3D Touch hardware